# Using require_once in a static class

Tags: cassandra, php-5.3

I am requiring two classes from the PHPCassa project into my class. Before I made my Class static I was able to call the method in selectColumnFamily. But now it does not work. Is there a way around this? Also is this the best strategy? I just want to be able to not have to re-connect to the Cassandra DB every time. So if I use CASSANDRA:: will it only connect once or multiple times?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class CASSANDRA {

    protected static $config = array();
    protected static $keyspace = NULL;
    protected static $servers = array();
    public static $pool = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {

        require_once ('phpcassa/connection.php');
        require_once ('phpcassa/columnfamily.php');

        // Test the config group name
        $config = Kohana::config('cassandra');

        self::$servers = $config['servers'];
        self::$keyspace = $config['keyspace'];

        self::$pool = new ConnectionPool($this->keyspace, $this->servers);

    }

    public static function selectColumnFamily($column_family_name)
    {

        return new ColumnFamily(self::$pool, $column_family_name);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"... Also, don't put require_once in your __construct. Require_once means you can include it only ONCE (so you can construct only 1 object, because the second time it will throw an error). Put it at the beginning of the file.

Comment: This is the error I get if I do what you propose: ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function describe_keyspace() on a non-object. This describe_keyspace() is found in PHPClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first you are using $this to access static variables, this is wrong:

```
self::$pool = new ConnectionPool($this->keyspace, $this->servers);
```

You should use `self::` instead of `$this->`.

But the main problem is: **the constructor is not called when using the static methods of a class!** (well, unless you did a `new CASSANDRA()` just before, but that makes no sense to do that).

Here, you setup the connection in the constructor, but if you don't call it, then `selectColumnFamily` will fail because it will try to use a connection not set.

A quick way to fix that is to rename the `__construct()` method to `static init()`, and do that when using the class:

```
CASSANDRA::init();
$foo = CASSANDRA::selectColumnFamily(...);
```

But I highly encourage you to read a good tutorial and use OOP correctly, using objects and not static classes.

Comment: Sorry about leaving the $this... I have work with OOP... But I haven't gotten this far before. This is why I am calling for help. Here is the new version: http://pastebin.com/sfrZZRq9 If I am not wrong the connection is made... The problem is that this way I cannot access the other class/methodes after I use CASSANDRA::connection(); I used to be able to do new CASSANDRA(); and it would make the class/methodes accessible in the methode and class that it was loaded in... Not with static... I want to make those methods and class accessible.

Comment: The problem is that if I put in my index the require_once I get this error:  [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function describe_keyspace() on a non-object An error that is found in PHPCassa library. But I don't understand why. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the problem with the suggestion I made ? Did you try it ? What happens then ?

Comment: Yes I did: http://pastebin.com/DKJTPuxj It works! BUT! One little problem if I call CASSANDRA::selectColumnFamily() two times... It will show ~Hey!~ two times... This tells me it connects two times... Thats bad I just want it to connect once... How can I do this... So that every time I call selectColumnFamily I don't reconnect to the DB? Thanks again.

Comment: Once again, you didn't do what I suggested, re-read the final part of my answer. You need to call `init()` (once) and `selectColumnFamily()` **after**. **Don't** call `init()` **in** `selectColumnFamily()`.

Comment: Do you even read what I say ?? I corrected another of your mistake: http://pastebin.com/0kC7fCm7

Comment: I did read. I just added the self::init(); in the select... to test it out. I saw your other modification, you removed the "require_once". I need it. Because if I put it in another place it sends an error. It does work with it inside the init(); Like I said everything is working. I am just trying to make it so I don't have to call init(); every time. That IF the connection as been made it does not do it again. Or if the init(); was already used it won't use it again. That's what I am trying to do. Thanks again for your help. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, what do you not understand : http://pastebin.com/kzwyAYwv should work. Just call init() once, and then that's it ! Like you said "so I don't have to call init(); every time". With that, you have to call init() only once, at the begining of your script.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that I am using a framework. Where everything is separated in modules and some are called some times. I don't want to call init(); in every page of code that I have... incase the page might be called... So I need to be possible to know if the init(); as already been called this way I don't have to called it again in another file... Thanks again...

Comment: Mathieu it works Thanks... But I have multiple pages of code where some are called some times others not. So I don't want to put init(); on everyone of the pages and risk that it will called multiple times. Because it will have a negative impact on the performance. Thanks again... It's my fault... I am not being clear enough.

Comment: This is maybe not the best code ever but: http://pastebin.com/ft1iBPBh. You just have to check if the connection has already been made.